# Django filtering with list and specific data

Tags: django

I'm sorry for the weird title. I don't know how to explain my problem in a short sentence. I'm trying to filter my model with a list but sometimes query returns multiple rows. For example:

```
all_pos [1,2,3]
query = MyModel.objects.filter(pos__in=all_pos)
```

The query above returns a list of rows from the database but second item in the list returns two rows with B and C in the second column.

```
1, A, word
2, B, word
2, C, word
3, A, word
4, C, word
```

But I only want the row with B on the second row and not losing 4th row with C. How can I filter this further so I can achieve the result below.

```
1, A, word
2, B, word
3, A, word
4, C, word
```

Comment: It seems you want to have results, distinct. Have you tried `distinct()` at the end of your query?

(`query = MyModel.objects.filter(pos__in=all_pos).distinct()`)

Comment: Thank you for your response. `distinct()` doesn't work for me because I want to select which row I want to keep based on the second column.

Comment: please specify the column name which have the values like A, B, C

Comment: @MukulKumar I'm guessing you're talking about `distinct()` function. I already did. It's not something I'm looking for. I have to tell Django that "I want column_1=2 and column_2=B". This will be done for hundreds of rows. If I use for loop, it's slow

Answer (score 0):

Your specifications are still not very clear. You need to specify by what logic you keep a result vs other.

But what I deduce, is you want the results ordered by col 1 ASC and col 2 alphabetically and distinct on col 1.

```
all_pos = [1, 2, 3, 4]
query = MyModel.objects.filter(pos__in=all_pos).order_by('col1', 'col2').distinct('col1')
```

Otherwise you will need 2 passes maybe like:

```
all_pos = [1, 2, 3, 4]
final_results = []
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(pos__in=all_pos)
for row in col1_qs:
    if custom_logic_with(row.col2):
        final_results.append(row)
```

Comment: Thank you. I should've been more clear in my question. In your example, any row that contains C will be discarded but I only want to discard on the second row. And I want to apply this logic to every single row with specific second_column data.

Comment: on what basis do you prefer the 2 B instead of 2 C in the results?

Comment: I just want to keep `4, C, word` but discard `2, C, word`. Is it impossible with Django?